# Gridview full width separators

Tags: android, gridview

I have `ArrayList` of some data. `ArrayList` includes different category of objects (cat 1, cat 2, cat 3, ...). I want to display my list in `GridView`.

My xml looks:

```
 <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gv_my_grid"
                style="@style/fill_wrap"
                android:cacheColorHint="@null"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
```

And all works great.

GridView looks like:

```
|item 1 (cat 1)| |item 2 (cat 1)| |item 3 (cat 1)|
|item 4 (cat 1)| |item 5 (cat 2)| |item 6 (cat 2)|
|item 7 (cat 3)| |item 8 (cat 3)| |item 9 (cat 3)|
```

But now I want to place full width horisontal separator line between different category items. It must look like:

```
___________category_1_____________________________
|item 1 (cat 1)| |item 2 (cat 1)| |item 3 (cat 1)|
|item 4 (cat 1)| 
___________category_2_____________________________
|item 5 (cat 2)| |item 6 (cat 2)|
___________category_1_____________________________
|item 7 (cat 3)| |item 8 (cat 3)| |item 9 (cat 3)|
```

Is this possible?  Cause all what I found - only `ListView` implementation.

**Edit:**

I was asked to add the code for my adapter. I think `getView` method will be enough.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final Holder holder;
        final View cell;
        if (null == view) {
            cell = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.gi_my_item, null);
            holder = new Holder(cell);
            cell.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            cell = view;
            holder = (Holder) cell.getTag();
        }
        holder.item = this.items.get(position);
        holder.textField.setText(holder.item.someText);
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Its ok.. you need to use sectioned adapter.. Look http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/ library.. You can use this..

Comment: Oh... thanks. I think - this is the best, I would have been able to find.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` to do the stuff.

Here is the code how to do this.

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
```

that creates the grid with three columns.

Use `setSpanSizeLookup()` method to have a callback to return the column span of each item.

```
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return (elementsAdapter.getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_HEADER) ? 3 : 1;
            }
        });
```

that will made three column span when it was the header type.

Also, you have to make two of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and use will need `getItemViewType()` to differ from item views and header views in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

I made some sample code for it.
https://github.com/j796160836/GridLayoutManagerDemo

---

Reference:
https://medium.com/android-bites/grid-layout-with-header-3f2966181c4d

Answer (score 0):

To reach this purpose,,You have to composite `GridView` in a `ListView`. with a `CustomAdapter` you can do that, `ListView` as parent and `GridView` as `row_item`.